# How to handle task cancellation using ContinueWith?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, cancellationtokensource

I've got the following example:

```
public void Run()
{
    var ctc = new CancellationTokenSource();

    try
    {
        DoAsync(ctc).Wait();

        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }
    catch (AggregateException exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inside try-catch block");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(exception);

        exception.Handle(ex =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return true;
        });
    }
}

private async Task DoAsync(CancellationTokenSource ctc)
{
    Console.WriteLine("DoAsync started");

    await Task.Run(() =>
                Console.WriteLine("DoAsync Run"),
                ctc.Token
            )
            .ContinueWith(antecedent =>
                Console.WriteLine("DoAsync Run cancelled"),
                TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled
            );

    Console.WriteLine("DoAsync finished");
}
```

I've created a method (*DoAsync*) that does some asynchronous work and can be cancelled at any time.

As you can see Task.Run gets a cancellation token. For this reason I created continuation task with *continuationOptions = TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled*.

As a result I expected continuation task to be called only when cancellation is requested and in other cases - ignored.

But in my implementation task returned by *ContinueWith* throws an exception when its antecedent task is not being cancelled:

```
DoAsync started
DoAsync Run

Inside try-catch block
System.AggregateException...

A task was canceled.
```

I can fix this by adding another *ContinueWith* as in the example below:

```
await Task.Run(() =>
        Console.WriteLine("DoAsync Run"),
        ctc.Token
    )
    .ContinueWith(antecedent =>
        Console.WriteLine("DoAsync Run cancelled"),
        TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled
    )
    .ContinueWith(antecedent => { });
```

And this code doesn't throw any exceptions.

But can I handle the cancellation using single *ContinueWith* properly?

Comment: Have you tried only passing the token, not the token source?

Comment: @Fildor, I agree that I should pass the token instead of the token source. But how does it solve my problem?

Comment: It probably won't. That's why it's only a comment. But maybe it will reduce side-effects. I don't see an obvious reason why your code should not work as intended ... (yet)

Comment: If you are using await, why are you using ContinueWith? The whole point of await is so you just continue on the next line with whatever is supposed to happen after the task. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is there a reason you are combining async/await and continue with? you could re-create it with a try/catch around the await and catching `catch (OperationCanceledException ex) when ex.CancellationToken.Equals(ctc.Token) { Console.WriteLine("DoAsync Run cancelled"); } `

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain, AlexDev, the reason I do it is just to try to handle task cancellation by ContinueWith method avoiding usage of try-catch blocks. The try-catch block it the example is used just to show that my code does not work as I want and expect. Also I can be wrong b/c I'm new to asynchronous code in C#.

Comment: @VladyslavYefremov: You shouldn't use `ContinueWith` at all. Using `await` with `try`/`catch` results in more maintainable code.

Answer (score 4):

The remarks for `ContinueWith` specifically state:

> If the continuation criteria specified through the *continuationOptions* parameter are not met, the continuation task will be canceled instead of scheduled.

Since the criteria you specified for the antecedent weren't met, (namely, it wasn't cancelled) the continuation was set to be cancelled.  You awaited the cancelled task, which therefore result in `DoAsync` faulting with an operation cancelled exception.